# Dns.GetHostAddresses() only returns IPv6 addresses . How to get Local IPv4?

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

According to Dotnet reference ,

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("")
```

should return IPv4 addresses . However I am getting only IPv6  on my windows 7 machine. I tried the program on a different windows 7 still the same result. It only returned IPv4 correctly on an XP machine.

If I try ,

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("");
```

It now correctly returns one IPv4 and one IPv6 .
How do I get IPv4 from GetHostAddresses() because I don't want to use GetHostEntry(). It looks up the DNS.

Also, say for a computer with 1 Network card, the code returns an array of 2 identical IPv6 . Is this normal ?

Comment: What have you tried..? have you tried looking here first 
[MSDN GetHostAddres](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)

Comment: I tried Dns.GetHostAddresses("") , but I got results which were unexpected as I described above. I hope someone can give me a clue.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("example.com");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList.First(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork); // ipv4
```

It's normal to have two ipv6 addresses, one which contains your MAC address which guarantees its uniqueness, and another which doesn't to increase your privacy/security. But I don't know why yours would be *identical*.

Comment: I should add I am trying to get my own local LAN ip. Dns.GetHostEntry() queries DNS so I would like to use GetHostAddresses("")  instead

Comment: What happens when you replace "example.com" with "", or Dns.GetHostName()?

Comment: GetHostEntry() & GetHostName() work correctly, but the issue I have is with .GetHostAddresses() returning only IPv6 addresses

Comment: I'm also running Windows 7. When I try the example code on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.100).aspx I get back:
GetHostAddresses() returns:
    fe80::10a5:fae2:f62c:2503%13
    10.2.4.22

Not sure why you're only getting ipv6. Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. On my ipv4 only machine if I use node.js and do a `require('dns').lookup("google.com", {all:true}, (err, addresses) => { console.log(addresses); });` I get both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses but if I use `Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com")` the returned `IpHostEntry.AddressList` only has the ipv4 address.